# Finite product of sines

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, numerical-methods

What is the origin of the formula
$$ 
\prod_{k=1}^n \sin\theta_k=
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\frac
        {n}{2}\rfloor}}{2^n}\sum_{e\in S}\cos(e_1\theta_1+\cdots+e_n\theta_n)\prod_{j=1}^n e_j &\text{if $n$ is even}, \\
\displaystyle
\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\frac
        {n}{2}\rfloor}}{2^n}\sum_{e\in S}\sin(e_1\theta_1+\cdots+e_n\theta_n)\prod_{j=1}^n e_j &\text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
where $e_1, \ldots, e_n\in \{-1, 1\}$
which can be found in the [Wikipedia list of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)?

**Further questions**

- As the related Wikipedia entry doesn't contain noting on these matters, could someone provide me a proof of this result?
- Moreover is it applicable for real computations?

Comment: The proof uses the first four Product-to-sum identities and induction on $n$.